# Model a 3D Point Pattern using spatstat

Tags: r, spatstat

Is there any way to fit a spatial statistical model to 3d data in spatstat?

I have tried using the functions such as ppm and kppm but they are not working for pp3

Comment: Please give us a sample of data and an idea of the model you want to fit. Otherwise anyone who hazards a guess at what you are looking for is likely to be wasting their time.

Answer (score 0):

This is not yet supported in `spatstat` (that is, the model-fitting functions `ppm`, `kppm` and `mppm` do not accept three-dimensional point pattern data).

We are working on it.